# How to get products based on a count on a field in this table with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm working on Laravel 5.8

Let's say we have a table products like this:

id | product_type_id |...

1  |______1_______|...

2  |______2_______|...

3  |______2_______|...

4  |______3_______|...

I would like to know how to get the all the products which "share" a product type.

In other words, I would like to get all the products except those whose product_type_id is unique in the table.

I know who to do it in a foreach loop but I would like to take advantage of the resources of using Laravel.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Laravel way of doing it would be using Eloquent relationships along with `has()` and `whereHas()`, like this:

```php
$products = Product::whereHas('type', function ($builder) {
    $builder->whereKey(Type::has('products', '>=', 2)->pluck('id'));
})->get();
```

I'm assuming you have defined `Product` and `Type` models and connected them together:

- `Product` belongsTo `Type`
- `Type` hasMany `Product`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly you could do something like this.

First, make sure your `ProductType` model has a products relationship defined.
*(I assume it does based on your Products table.)*

Then you can query based on a relationship count using the Eloquent model method `has`.

**Example:**

```php
ProductType::with('products')->has('products', '>', 1)->get();
```

The `with('products')` is optional. It simply grabs the Products at the same time to avoid additional queries. The `whereHas` method also works but is really only necessary if you need to filter the relationship based on more complex parameters.

You could also use the `has`/`whereHas` method inside the `Product` model using an inverse *(ie belongsTo)* relationship to get the same thing but inverted. It really depends on how you want the data presented to you.

**Example:**

```php
Product::whereIn(
    'product_type_id',
    ProductType::has('products', '>', 1)->pluck('id')
)->get();
```

To sum it all up the first way will give you:

```
ProductType => Product
```

While the second example will give you:

```
Product => ProductType
```

---

See the related [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) for more info.

Hope that helps!